# Android searchView, Show first part of long string instead of last

Tags: android, searchview

If I set the SearchView query to a string that is longer than the box, how do I make it such that it is the first part of the string that is visible instead of the last part? (I am using it as a navigation/search bar for a WebView.)

I do

```
mySearchView.setQuery("Start of long string.... at the end.", false);
```

And want it to show

```
Start of long
```

instead of

```
at the end
```

It's always showing me the end. I, essentially, want it scrolled back to the start of the text.

Edit: I do want the complete text to be there, just scrolled to the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember well you need to get a hold of the `EditText` in the `SearchView` and then set the ellipsize on it.

```
int id = mySearchView.getContext()
    .getResources()
    .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText editText = (EditText) mySearchView.findViewById(id);
editText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

If you don't want to ellipsize you can use the same method and set the position in the EditText.

```
int id = mySearchView.getContext()
    .getResources()
    .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText editText = (EditText) mySearchView.findViewById(id);
editText.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: The second set of code worked perfectly, thanks! I did edit your answer to correct searchView.find... to mySearchView.find...

Comment: I am getting a NullPointerException. EditText is null

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Android: showing text in EditText from start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052012/android-showing-text-in-edittext-from-start) I would try this

```
mySearchView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
if (hasFocus == false) {  // lost focus
   mEdittext.setSelection(0,0);
}
}
});
```

also, check this [Android SearchView OnFocusChangeListener: onFocusChange is not called at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944238/android-searchview-onfocuschangelistener-onfocuschange-is-not-called-at-all), otherwise I can't help you

Comment: SearchView doesn't have a setSelection function, but thanks for trying!

Comment: I am sorry, I only searched to find if searchviews have setOnFocusChangeListener, I assumed it would have a setSelection. Try adding android:ellipsize="start" to your searchview in your layout file

Comment: I do want all the text to be in the box, just scrolled such that the beginning shows,

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions didn't worked for me. 
I was using appcompat v7 action bar and this worked!

```
EditText editText = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
editText.setSelection(0);
```